# create login and logout session

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create login and logout session

My table in MySQL database is looking like this

```
CREATE TABLE `login` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `username` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;
```

and MySQL connection named as `config.inc`

```
<?php

 $hostname = 'localhost';        // Your MySQL hostname. Usualy named as 'localhost',     so you're NOT necessary to change this even this script has already     online on the internet.
$dbname   = ''; // Your database name.
$username = '';             // Your database username.
$password = '';                 // Your database password. If your database has no     password, leave it empty.

// Let's connect to host
mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or DIE('Connection to host is failed,     perhaps the service is down!');
// Select the database
mysql_select_db($dbname) or DIE('Database name is not available!');

?>
```

My `index.php` page looking like this

```
<?php

// Inialize session
session_start();

// Check, if user is already login, then jump to secured page
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
header('Location: securedpage.php');
}

?>
<html>

<head>
<title>PHPMySimpleLogin 0.3</title>
</head>

<body>

 <h3>User Login</h3>

<table border="0">
<form method="POST" action="loginproc.php">
<tr><td>Username</td><td>:</td><td><input type="text" name="username" size="20">        </td></tr>
<tr><td>Password</td><td>:</td><td><input type="password" name="password"     size="20">    </td></tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td><input type="submit" value="Login"></td></tr>
</form>
</table>

</body>

</html>
```

Checking username and password file named as `loginproc.php`

```
<?php

// Inialize session
session_start();

// Include database connection settings
include('config.inc');

// Retrieve username and password from database according to user's input
$login = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE (username = '" .     mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']) . "') and (password = '" .     mysql_real_escape_string(md5($_POST['password'])) . "')");

// Check username and password match
 if (mysql_num_rows($login) == 1) {
// Set username session variable
$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
// Jump to secured page
 header('Location: securedpage.php');
}
else {
// Jump to login page
header('Location: index.php');
}

?>
```

My secure page code named as `securedpage.php`

```
<?php

// Inialize session
session_start();

// Check, if username session is NOT set then this page will jump to login page
if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
header('Location: index.php');
}

?>
<html>

<head>
<title>Secured Page</title>
</head>

<body>

<p>This is secured page with session: <b><?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></b>
<br>You can put your restricted information here.</p>
<p><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></p>

</body>

</html>
```

And finally logout page named as `logout.php`

```
<?php

// Inialize session
session_start();

// Delete certain session
unset($_SESSION['username']);
// Delete all session variables
// session_destroy();

// Jump to login page
header('Location: index.php');

?>
```

Now my problem is when I am entering username and password it will stay only at `index.php` , it is not going to another page. Please see this code and tell me when I am doing wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: Consider using PDO or mysqli instead of mysql.

Comment: there might be 'query' issue, debug your form submit and response line by line.. print your values after each execution

Answer (score 4):

**First** of all, the [regular mysql functions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) will be deprecated in PHP 5.5.0.

**Secondly**, you're searching inside a table called `user` while you named yours `login`.

And ... you don't need to filter md5.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

As per PHP 5.5 All the mysql_ * functions are deprecated. Try to use abstraction layers or mysqli.

In your  loginproc.php
         You should start your session after successful validation of username and password so use session_start() in if condition

```
        if (mysql_num_rows($login) == 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, You may have more than one users with the same credentials.

Second, you may have no users with the entered username or password.

Third, in SQL Query `password = '" .     mysql_real_escape_string(md5($_POST['password']))`

change into

```
password = '" .    md5(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']))
```

And check the table name "login" or "user" ??

try this

Answer (score 0):

In `securedpage.php` use:

```
...
if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])==null)
{
    header('Location: index.php');
}
...
```

instead of:

```
...
if (!isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
    header('Location: index.php');
}
...
```

Do the same in `index.php`

Answer (score 0):

```
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ (E_NOTICE | E_WARNING));
if(session_is_registered['username']){
        unset($_SESSION['username']);
        session_destroy($_SESSION['username']);
        print "<script>alert('Anda berhasil logout'); location = '/'; </script>";
}
```